# Go to next/Previous page on when i release UIScrollView after dragging

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

I have a full page vertical scrollview with paging enable when i release it before dragging less then half distance it went back to original position. I want it to go to next page when i release it even if i don't scroll it half way. 
Is it possible?

Comment: Anything is possible, but in order to get what you want you may need to get rid of paging and build in your own paging functionality...

Comment: Disable paging and implement your preferred style of paging using the delegate callback `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`